# Javascript remove array from object where id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry for my bad English. If I have an array:

```
const myobj = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'First...'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Second...
}];
```

How can I remove, for example, the object with `id` `2`? To leave the array only with first object. Which functions should I use? Thanks in advance.

---

Found solution:

```
function removeByKey(array, params){
    array.some(function(item, index) {
        if(array[index][params.key] === params.value){
            array.splice(index, 1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return array;
}
```

Then

```
removeByKey(myobj, {
    key: 'id',
    value: 2
})
```

http://jsforallof.us/2015/07/08/remove-object-by-key-from-array/

Comment: Do you want to mutate the array? Then use `splice`, otherwise use `filter` and ignore the matching element

Comment: I don't see an array with id 2, only an object.

Comment: You should add a new answer to your own question if you found a solution.

Comment: Not to forget, you should `return array.some` as its result will return a new array and not an in place mutation

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.filter` which produces new array based on the provided condition.

```js
const myobj = [{ id: 1, name: 'First...' }, { id: 2, name: 'Second...' }];

console.log(myobj.filter(v => v.id !== 2));
```

Similarly you can use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
const myobj = [{ id: 1, name: 'First...' }, { id: 2, name: 'Second...' }];

console.log(myobj.reduce((acc, v) => v.id !== 2 ? acc.concat(v) : acc, []));
```

Comment: Reduce is so overly complicated for a filter or a splice problem (depending on whether or not he wants to mutate the original)

Comment: @Icepickle It is a little bit more complicated and I have included it only as an option, but it is the most fundamental out of the functional methods so it is good to be aware of that option.

Comment: but it doesn't match the problem, for the problemof filtering there is little use of reduce, not even thinking about concat on every iteration, it is pointless for the problem at hand

Comment: @Icepickle Please, let me repeat myself. `I have included it only as an option` and I think that `it is good to be aware of that option`.  Arguing over it seems rather pointless to me.

Answer (score 0):

first, you have an array, not an object in `myobj`, one way of many you could do this is to remove the item by filtering:

```
const myFilteredArray = myobj.filter(i => i.id !== 2);
```

See the javascript [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Vue & socket.io. I have table with recent games (array) and I would like to remove game which ended from this array, my socket returns only ended game id. So I need to find in array key with this id and remove it from array.

Answer (score 0):

Using filter and assuming myobj is not constant you can do the following:

```
myobj = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'First...'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Second...'
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Third...'
}
];

myobj = myobj.filter(v => v.id !== 2);
console.log(myobj);
```